# Where can I find Delta flight schedule information in a structured format?

Tags: flight-schedules

I downloaded Delta flight schedules from [here](http://www.delta.com/content/dam/delta-www/pdfs/flight_schedules.pdf) but would like this information in a spreadsheet. Does something like that exist?

Comment: There are APIs to booking systems for this sort of thing to give you up-to-date information.

Comment: @MikeFoxtrot do you have a link for reference on such APIs ?

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680408/is-there-any-api-for-getting-flight-fare) from SO.